# php a href display data from mysql database and link it to a new page

Tags: php, mysql

I have a php & mysql search script which is working, after result displayed users can click below link and  it will open a new page and display more mysql info, i am stuck with linking the ahref link ($field2name) to the new page (getprofile.php).

Now the problem is getprofile.php showed nothing and displayed 0 results, however i tried to put static data in getprofile.php it is working properly and can show profile data from mysql, can anyone enlighten me what is missing?

from search page user can click this link:

```
<td><a href="getprofile.php?'.$field2name.'" target = "_blank">'.$field2name.'</td>
```

getprofile.php:

```
<?php
 $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","password","demo");
 $pkey = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET[$field2name]);
// $pkey = "4027500001"; <-------if i put static data it can show profile data
    
  $query = "SELECT * FROM nhc WHERE code =" . $pkey;
    $result = $conn->query($query);


if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "<table border='1'><tr><th>code</th><th>Name</th><th>class</th><th>AM</th><th>May GA</th><th>June GA</th></tr>";
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr><td>".$row["code"]."</td> <td>".$row["name"]."</td> <td> ".$row["class"]."</td>  <td>".$row["am"]."</td> <td>".$row["may"]."</td><td>".$row["june"]. "</td></tr>";
  
    }
    echo "</table>";
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not assigning $field2name in any variable. Moreover your quotes are mismatching and are not forming a well formatted url

```
<td><a href="getprofile.php?value=<?=$field2name?>" target = "_blank">'<?=$field2name?></td>
```

now to get the value
use `$_GET['value']`

Answer (score 1):

You need to give the `GET` parameter a name so that you can access it in PHP:

```
<td><a href="getprofile.php?code='.$field2name.'" target = "_blank">'.$field2name.'</td>
```

then in PHP:

```
$pkey = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['code']);
```

Note that you should use prepared statements to protect yourself from SQL injection; `mysql_real_escape_string` is not sufficient (see [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)). For example:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM nhc WHERE code = ?";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param('i', $_GET['code']);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
```

Comment: `mysql_real_escape_string` is non-existent

Comment: @Dharman it still exists in PHP5.x and below. Anyway I tried to direct OP to the right way to do things to no avail...